# sort backbone collection based on model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection which is rendered in a table. I would like to make the table sortable based on certain attributes the collection has, like "task_status","task_group". I've being reading the backbone documentation about collection.comparator,nd collection.sort.
How can I get this done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) function is used to compare two models in the collection and it can compare them in any (consistent) way that it wants to. In particular, it can choose which model attribute to use so you could have something like this in your collection:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.sort_key = 'id';
},
comparator: function(a, b) {
    // Assuming that the sort_key values can be compared with '>' and '<',
    // modifying this to account for extra processing on the sort_key model
    // attributes is fairly straight forward.
    a = a.get(this.sort_key);
    b = b.get(this.sort_key);
    return a > b ?  1
         : a < b ? -1
         :          0;
}
```

and then you just need some methods on the collection to change the `sort_key` and call [`sort`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort):

```
sort_by_thing: function() {
    this.sort_key = 'thing';
    this.sort();
}
```

In older Backbones, calling `sort` will trigger a `"reset"` event whereas newer versions will trigger a `"sort"` event. To cover both cases you can listen to both events and re-render:

```
// in the view...
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('reset sort', this.render, this);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7y9CC/

You can also use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead of [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) to help you avoid zombies:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sort', this.render);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nG6EJ/

Comment: Can I use this pattern in a situation where the sort fields are strings

Comment: @MrFoh: Yes, `>` and `<` work on strings, the `s` attribute in the demo is a string.

Comment: Note this example no longer works because Backbone no longer fires the reset event on sort. It fires the sort event.

Comment: @BryanDowning: Thanks for the heads up, I updated things to account for newer releases of Backbone.

Comment: Interesting, apparently adding that initialize line and comparator to the collection is enough to have it auto-sort when instantiated.

Comment: @NoBugs: That's because the constructor will (AFAIK) call `add` and that will insert things in their proper position.

Answer (score 20):

@mu-is-too-short's answer is good, except there's an easier way to compare the field values:

The easiest way to sort the collection based on a field, is to provide a comparator function that returns the exact field's value you want to sort by. This kind of comparator causes Backbone to call `sortBy` function, instead of `sort`, which then does that complex comparison on it's own and you don't have to worry about the logic.

So in essence, you don't have to provide a complex comparator function, unless you have a more advanced need for determining the order.

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    sort_key: 'id', // default sort key
    comparator: function(item) {
        return item.get(this.sort_key);
    },
    sortByField: function(fieldName) {
        this.sort_key = fieldName;
        this.sort();
    }
});
```

After this you can just call the collection's `sortByField` -function with a string that represents the key that you want to sort by.
For example:

```
collection.sortByField('name');
```

Modified @my-is-too-short's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NTez2/39/

Comment: Note this example no longer works because Backbone no longer fires the reset event on sort. It fires the sort event.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I updated the example to accommodate that change: http://jsfiddle.net/NTez2/39/

Comment: The big problem with the single argument comparator (and `_.sortBy`) is that you can't switch between ascending and descending ordering on a string in any sane fashion. Descending on numbers is easy as you can negate numbers but negating a string isn't so easy. You also can't sort by several keys without mashing them into a single string and that takes care to get it right.

Answer (score 3):

@jylauril's answer helps out tremendously, but needed to modify the demo (perhaps slight changes in backbone since it was posted?)

Looks like you need to trigger a render after you've sorted.

```
$('#by-s').click(function() {
  c.sortByField('s');
  v.render();
});
```

Updated @my-is-too-short's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NTez2/13/